# Azure DevOps Delivery Plans 2.0 - to show completed items when they are with status Ready?

Tags: azure

Is it possible to show on the timeline view the Epic with its children, but say that items in status "Ready" are marked as completed as opposed to when they get to status "Done"?

[board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJLUn.png)

On the example screenshot you can see that there are 13/35 user stories that are with status "Done", but out of the rest there are user stories that are with status "Ready" which we also refer to as completed. My question is - is it possible for them to also be visible and marked as "Done" in this view?

Comment: Hi Daniel I think more detail here and maybe a screen shot would help as it may be hard for people to understand what your question relates to

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @RuSs - I've updated the main posted and published a screenshot.